# Stop SSMS from scripting SPs using sp_executesql?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssms

When I use SSMS to script a stored procedure, it wraps the script in a sp_executesql statement which bugs me. Is there a way to stop SSMS from doing this and use a straight CREATE PROCEDURE...?

**EDIT**: I meant SSMS not SSIS

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Turn off the "Include IF NOT EXISTS" option.

It's at Tools..Options, then click "Scripting" on the explorer pane of the dialog that pops-up.  the "IF NOT EXISTS" option is in the second group from the top (Object Scripting options).

Answer (score 3):

[Execute SQL Task Editor (General Page)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188957(SQL.90).aspx)

Look at the "QueryIsStoredProcedure" and "BypassPrepare" options