# How to Stop SSMS 2012 from scripting SPs using sp_executesql

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I realise this is a very similar question to [Stop SSMS from scripting SPs using sp_executesql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263588/stop-ssms-from-scripting-sps-using-sp-executesql)

However, they seem to have changed the behaviour with SSMS 2012.

If you have the 'Check for existence' option selected, as in:

[image]

... it now generates an IF NOT EXISTS for the proc about to be created, **as well** as an IF EXISTS for the previous drop proc, if, as I usually do, I select the DROP and CREATE option:

[image]

This forces it to script the CREATE using sp_executesql.  It's pointless, since you don't need the IF NOT EXISTS check on the CREATE, if the DROP has just dropped it.

It doesn't seem possible to have the one without the other.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't do this without the dynamic SQL because a stored procedure has to be in its own batch. Therefore you can't say:

```
IF <some condition>
  <start a new batch>
```

The only way to keep that in the same batch is to use `sp_executesql`.

If you're going to script the `DROP` and `CREATE` simultaneously, just do it without the check for object existence. This will give you:

```
DROP PROCEDURE ...;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE ...;
GO
```

Who cares if the `DROP` fails? (It shouldn't, because you just scripted from it!)

If you're scripting this for another system that *might* have the object, you'll get an error message for the `DROP` when it doesn't, but the `CREATE` will still happen, so you can ignore the `DROP` errors. If you really want you can manually wrap the `DROP` statements in `TRY/CATCH` but I don't think it's necessary.

If you need to do this for a lot of procedures, or if you really need the process to not generate benign errors, I suggest you abandon Management Studio's primitive scripting options and use a 3rd party tool for this. They'll have already dealt with many of the issues you haven't yet come across, but will. I blogged about this:

http://bertrandaaron.wordpress.com/2012/04/20/re-blog-the-cost-of-reinventing-the-wheel/

Comment: Thanks for this - I suspected as much.  What I really want is an option for both the IF EXISTS, and the IF NOT EXISTS.  I can ignore the DROP error for now, but these scripts get run by an automatic process, and at some point I'll be needing to parse the script logs to check for errors.  They just seem to have made one of their retrograde steps with this change.

Comment: They updated the wording (which might be partly my fault). See http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/624075/include-if-not-exists-clause-impacts-drop-scripting http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/242799/ssms-certain-scripting-options-yield-dynamic-sql and https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/242795/ssms-certain-scripting-options-do-not-work-for-modify

Comment: Yes, I'm not bothered about the wording.  It's the fact that if I want the IF EXISTS (to prevent the DROP error), I'm forced also to have the IF NOT EXISTS on the create, which in turn forces the create to be an argument to sp_executesql, which I also don't want - since any inadvertent typos will not generate obvious errors.  It was fine before - the IF EXISTS was there by default, and I didn't have the IF NOT EXISTS switched on.  In *not* having the IF EXISTS a separate option, for me it's now worse than with SQL08.

Comment: Sorry, those options have been combined - there is no magic fix to decouple them.

Comment: Yes - grrrrrrrr.  I'm probably going to go back to SSMS from SQL 08.

Comment: You could also look at SMO - http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1833/generate-scripts-for-database-objects-with-smo-for-sql-server/

Comment: Well yes - I was hoping not to have to completely re-engineer what we do - for all the reasons you blogged :D

Comment: @usr That's why I suggested wrapping them in TRY/CATCH, or gave several other alternatives. I can't fix Management Studio for you, sorry. If it's more important that the script just runs, maybe generate one version with the if exists check (and live with the sp_executesql), and a cleaner version with the regular DDL, and source control one or the other or both.

Comment: I'm not asking you to fix SSMS.  Thanks for the various suggestions - the trouble is, we develop and maintain dozens of client databases, by remotely applying (over time) hundreds of scripts like this.  It was fine before, it's not now. Any extra work that we have to do, like additional customisation of each script beyond what SSMS generates, is a nuisance.  As with all breaking changes, we'll just have to find a workaround, or a completely different solution, if we want to move to SSMS 2012.

Comment: Sorry, that was a response to @usr, who has since deleted his comment for some reason.

Comment: @ChrisA, I hear you. this becomes a major pain in the ... when you want to put these files in version control and send a log of changes to your client. I gave up on Microsoft very long time ago. fortunately I have talent in writing programs and I wrote a program to do exactly what I want. right now I just use modify to look at procedure and haven't use "Script Procedure as ..." for long time

Answer (score 5):

The closest you can get to this functionality is to go under tools, options, SQL Server Object Explorer, Scripting, then set the Check for Object Existing to false.

The drawback is that if you do this then drops and creates will always try to drop even if the object does not exist.  The ideal solution would be a setting that allowed your script to look like the example below for creating Views, Procedures, and User-Defined Functions.

```
/****** Object:  View [dbo].[vEmployees]    Script Date: 9/14/2012 9:18:57 AM ******/
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.views WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[vEmployees]'))
DROP VIEW [dbo].[vEmployees]
GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vEmployees]
AS
    SELECT DISTINCT
        Employees.EmployeeID,
        FirstName,
        LastName
    from
        Employees
            JOIN Sales on Employees.EmployeeID=Sales.EmployeeID
GO
```

In short if the scripting engine thinks of the drop and create together in checking for object existance it does not need to put the condition on the create.

Answer (score 1):

I found a good solution to this problem.
You must make "two passes" when scripting.
During the first pass, select the options to Check for Existence AND for only the DROP script.
Then, on the second pass, de-select the option for Check for Existence and select the CREATE script.  In addition, use the option Append To File.  Then when running the generate scripts on the second pass, uncheck the option for "Overwrite File".  This will only work if you are generating a separate file for each object.

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled with the same issue. If you need to script out the objects for an entire database, you might want to consider ApexSQL Script. I tried several tools and ApexSQL scripted the objects exactly how I needed.
(if object exists, then drop. create the object). I believe it also works from the command-line. Note, it is shareware; I've only used the evaluation version because I only needed it a handful of times.

Below is an example of the output for a procedure after some configuration.

```
IF (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[myProcedure]') AND [type]='P'))
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[myProcedure]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.myProcedure
AS
    select 1 as a
GO
```